# XML too many decimals in product dimensions (Woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce, wpallimport

I'm curently struggling with a problem. I have an XML that is having 4 zeros after decimal in product dimensions and I need to remove the trailing zeros after the import...
Any ideas?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can try running each value through a custom PHP function which will remove the trailing zeros. During the import replace the value (e.g. `{price[0]}`) with something like this:

`[strip_trailing_zeroes_from_price({price[0]})]`

Also write the actual code and insert into the Function Editor on the Edit Import page:

```
function strip_trailing_zeroes_from_price( $price = null ) {
    if ( !empty( $price ) ) {
    // strip trailing zeroes from price
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Guide: https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/developers/custom-code/inline-php/